# Дублирование строки побуквенно в массив Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Стоит задача перевести буквы с переменной "s" в код букв в массив "mass", но машина ругается : list index out of range

```
while i < len(s):
  s[i] = int(mass[i])
  i = i + 1
```

Comment: Можно пример что есть и что нужно получить?

Comment: Пример: s[0] = п; s[1] = р; s[2] = и; s[3] = в; s[4] = е; s[5] = т
mass должен содержать  код символ

Comment: Чему равно ``i``? Что в ``s``? Что в ``mass``? Приведите [минимальный воспроизводимый фрагмент кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Не пробовали mass = s.split('')

Comment: Что такое mass, что такое s, какое начальное значение i? Приведите более полный код

Comment: А ещё вы не уточнили, какие именно коды букв вас интересуют

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего так:

```
mass = list(s.encode())
# или
mass = list(bytes(s))
```

Если исходная строка содержит кириллицу, например, то нужно указать кодировку:

```
mass = list(s.encode(encoding='cp1251'))
# или
mass = list(bytes(s, encoding='cp1251'))
```

Но эти варианты сработают только для однобайтовых кодировок. Для юникода подойдет вариант с `ord`, как в ответе MBo.

Comment: Китайцы, японцы и Emoji обидятся на такой ответ

Answer (score 2):

Оно?

```
s = 'AzЫ!'
print([ord(x) for x in s])
>>> 
[65, 122, 1067, 33]
```